# Python make a list of lists from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do I do this?

Below is my list of lists

```
[[0.0, 0.5884873389626358, 0.6396995276767564, 0.7329666273317014, 0.4842313879485761, 1.0], [0.0, 0.3198112142984678, 0.688061628145554, 0.9057703742992778, 0.4510016620800218, 1.0], [0.0, 0.8174664500409363, 0.6534818573661288, 0.7434609459640676, 0.625429283659689, 1.0], [0.0, 0.6671642766717503, 0.019976903098259637, 0.8374816423664811, 0.38608275062838593, 1.0], [0.17795385258743912, 0.32139709168355723, 0.0, 0.016863091072428376, 0.1259237700382603, 1.0], [0.0677184881194031, 1.0, 0.27760511005151, 0.0, 0.9794600361121459]]
```

I want to create a new list of lists which each new sublist corrosponds to a values position in the first list of lists.

So the first two sublists in the new list of list would be:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.17795385258743912, 0.0677184881194031], [0.5884873389626358, 0.3198112142984678, 0.8174664500409363, 0.6671642766717503, 0.32139709168355723, 1.0]]
```

I need it so no matter how big the first list is it can still compute it into the new list of lists.

For context im converting a csv column list of lists into a row list of lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a new list of lists, you can use another list comprehension with `zip`:

```
x = [list(items) for items in zip(*a)]
print (x)

#[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.17795385258743912, 0.0677184881194031], [0.5884873389626358, 0.3198112142984678, 0.8174664500409363, 0.6671642766717503, 0.32139709168355723, 1.0], [0.6396995276767564, 0.688061628145554, 0.6534818573661288, 0.019976903098259637, 0.0, 0.27760511005151], [0.7329666273317014, 0.9057703742992778, 0.7434609459640676, 0.8374816423664811, 0.016863091072428376, 0.0], [0.4842313879485761, 0.4510016620800218, 0.625429283659689, 0.38608275062838593, 0.1259237700382603, 0.9794600361121459]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need `zip`

```
data = [[0.0, 0.5884873389626358, 0.6396995276767564, 0.7329666273317014, 0.4842313879485761, 1.0], [0.0, 0.3198112142984678, 0.688061628145554, 0.9057703742992778, 0.4510016620800218, 1.0], [0.0, 0.8174664500409363, 0.6534818573661288, 0.7434609459640676, 0.625429283659689, 1.0], [0.0, 0.6671642766717503, 0.019976903098259637, 0.8374816423664811, 0.38608275062838593, 1.0], [0.17795385258743912, 0.32139709168355723, 0.0, 0.016863091072428376, 0.1259237700382603, 1.0], [0.0677184881194031, 1.0, 0.27760511005151, 0.0, 0.9794600361121459]]

print(list(zip(*data)))
#or print(list(map(list, zip(*data))))
```

**Output:**

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.17795385258743912, 0.0677184881194031),
 (0.5884873389626358,
  0.3198112142984678,
  0.8174664500409363,
  0.6671642766717503,
  0.32139709168355723,
  1.0),
 (0.6396995276767564,
  0.688061628145554,
  0.6534818573661288,
  0.019976903098259637,
  0.0,
  0.27760511005151),
 (0.7329666273317014,
  0.9057703742992778,
  0.7434609459640676,
  0.8374816423664811,
  0.016863091072428376,
  0.0),
 (0.4842313879485761,
  0.4510016620800218,
  0.625429283659689,
  0.38608275062838593,
  0.1259237700382603,
  0.9794600361121459)]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a list of tuples instead of list of lists?

Comment: @HenryYik. Yes. I just wanted to show that OP need to use `zip`